# Sub-Class multiple Cells

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

In my `UITableView` I have Four cell. Each cell has its own class. But I can only `return` one of the cells. Here is my code

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let firstCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FirstCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FirstTableViewCell



    let secondCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SecondCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SecondTableViewCell

    let thirdCelll = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ThirdCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ThirdTableViewCell

    let fourthCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FourthCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FourthTableViewCell





    return firstCell


}
```

How do I Correctly sub class and return them

Answer (score 1):

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0  // or your custom condition
    {    let firstCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FirstCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FirstTableViewCell
return firstCell
    }

    else if indexPath.row == 1{
        let secondCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SecondCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SecondTableViewCell
return secondCell
    }
    indexPath.row == 2{
        let thirdCelll = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ThirdCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ThirdTableViewCell
return thirdCelll
    }
    else{
        let fourthCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FourthCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FourthTableViewCell
return fourthCell
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This function is called multiple times. The `indexPath.row` would be used to determine which cell to return. You should check the value of this and only return the requested cell.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FirstCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FirstTableViewCell

    case 1:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SecondCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SecondTableViewCell

    case 2:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ThirdCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ThirdTableViewCell

    case 3:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FourthCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FourthTableViewCell
    }

    return cell;
}
```